# Show that $\operatorname{max}\{x^TAx: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x\geq 0, ||x||_2=1\} \leq \operatorname{max}\{x^THx: x\geq 0, ||x||_2=1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be nonnegative and consider the symmetric nonnegative matrix $H=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$. I want to show that
$$\operatorname{max}\{x^TAx: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x\geq 0, ||x||_2=1\} \leq \operatorname{max}\{x^THx: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x\geq 0, ||x||_2=1\}.$$

By nonnegative matrix and vector we mean that each entries are nonnegative.

This looks straightforward but I can’t put my finger on it. We have
$x^THx= \frac{1}{2} (x^TAx+ x^TA^Tx)$ and then what?

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\ x^TAx\ $ is a scalar, so $\ x^TAx=\big(x^TAx\big)^T=x^TA^Tx\ $, and hence
$$
x^THx=\frac{1}{2}\big(x^TAx+x^TA^Tx\big)=x^TAx\ .
$$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Oh that’s it. Thank you so much!